# Como generar un ejecutable .exe correctamente con py installer

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Utilizando pyinstaller para generar un archivo único .exe, sale el siguiente error:

Alguna solución? El paquete está formado por dos modulos .py con tkinter y el archivo  **init**.py vacio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sé que suena trivial, pero ¿Tus scripts corren correctamente?. Y para obtener más información del error, ¿Puedes compartir los errores que tira `pyinstaller` al correrlo desde la consola?

Comment: El archivo.exe se crea correctamente! Al intentar abrirlo es cuando da el error. Los scripts funcionan bien. No hago uso del __init__(self) en el modulo.

Comment: ¿Y si abres el ejecutable desde la consola te tira algún error en la misma que nos ayude a saber que está pasando?

Comment: Ejecutando desde consola sale el mismo error.

Comment: También probé con pip install auto-py-to-exe, que si da error al instalarlo. Por lo que no puedo utilizar auto-py

Comment: Me salen muchos errores PYZ-00.toc is non existent

Comment: Puede que se trate de problemas con las librerías. ¿Me puedes decir que versión de Python estas usando y todas las dependencias que importas en tu proyecto?

Comment: Tengo python 3.9.1 untilizo un modulo.py que llama a otro. Utilizo tkinter e imágenes .png.

Comment: Si el ejecutable creado contiene imágenes debes incluirlas como recursos, y al inicio de tu script añade `import sys, os; if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'): os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)` para que el directorio de trabajo del script sea aquel en el que se descomprimen los recursos.